# asyncio polling in the background with infinite printing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I would like to get a basic idea working in Python:

Let's say I have a blocking call to a function that reads the current speed of a car (I use python-can for this, and wait for the corresponding message to appear on the bus).

On the other hand, I have an infinite loop that prints as precisely as possible the speed of the car.

What I would like is the value of the speed to be updated directly, so that the infinite loop can print it as soon as it changes.

Right now I had three ideas:

- Call my `get_speed` function in the loop, and block. This works, but only if this is the only value I am willing to print (spoiler alert: it's not). If I want to print precisely the RPM too, I have to wait for the speed to be found, possibly missing multiple RPM value before.
- Create another "thread" (subprocess/multiprocessing/thread, whatever you call it) that updates a global variable. I know this works, but meh, I feel like I could have something smarter
- From what I saw in javascript, there is a way to ask a function for a result, and keep going until this result is found (this rings some CPU bells right now ahah). I kinda want something like this, which could make me do the following

```
speed = get_speed()
rpm = get_rpm()

while True:
        print("RPM: {0} - Speed: {1}".format(rpm, speed))
```

This would (in my fairy world) actually display something like this:

```
RPM: None - Speed: None  # Function haven't returned yet, waiting
RPM: None - Speed: None  # Same here
RPM: None - Speed: None  # Same here
RPM: 300 - Speed: None   # get_rpm has returned
RPM: 300 - Speed: None   # Nothing happened
RPM: 303 - Speed: 0      # get_rpm and get_speed have returned
RPM: 303 - Speed: 0
RPM: 312 - Speed: 0      # etc.
```

Right now what I have is something like this, which doesn't work (at all)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import asyncio
import random
from time import sleep

async def _can_get_speed():
    # My long function
    print ("In   can_get_speed")
    sleep(4)
    print ("Out  can_get_speed")
    r = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(r)
    return r

async def can_get_speed():
    return await asyncio.gather(_can_get_speed())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    speed = 0
    speed = loop.call_soon(can_get_speed, loop)
    loop.run_forever()


    while True:
        print("Speed: {0}".format(speed))
```

My two questions are:

1. Is this the most correct way to do it (--> asyncio, I mean), and
   if not what is ?
2. If it is, can somebody help me understanding
   asyncio better :)

Thanks in advance all!

Comment: Of course, get_speed and get_rpm would somehow recall each other at the end of each execution or find a way to get me the latest value at each call (I think there is something like this in python [generator with yield ?] )

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the expected result like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import asyncio
import random
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def can_get_speed(q):
    while True:
        print("IN get_speed")
        r = random.randint(1, 4)
        sleep(r)
        print("Return {0}".format(r))
        q.put(r)

def can_get_rpm(q):
    while True:
        print("IN get_rpm")
        r = random.randint(1, 4)
        sleep(r)
        print("Return {0}".format(r))
        q.put(r)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    q = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()

    p = Process(target=can_get_speed, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=can_get_rpm, args=(q2,))

    p.start()
    p2.start()

    speed = None
    rpm = None

    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            speed = q.get()
        if not q2.empty():
            rpm = q2.get()

        print("Speed: {0} - RPM: {1} - {2}".format(speed, rpm, datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Is there a smarter way ?